# Is it possible to replace/change an argument using bash bang (!) and history

Tags: bash, command-history

I am currently *swooning* over the `history` and `!` based featured for `bash` in Linux.

I am getting used to using `!!` and `!:<argc>` and similar features, but is there someway where for instance if I make a mistake by adding a wrong argument previously and then I could remove that false argument and use the command line again.

#### Example

If I make a mistake like the following:

```
      mv -r movableFolder/ targetFolder/
```

since there is no `-r` option for `mv`, I would like to remove it using some `!` trickery to make it :

```
      mv movableFolder/ targetFolder/
```

I know I can do from the above history command:

```
     mv !:2 !:3
```

but is there anyway to substitute `mv` with a `!` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hoho, I am glad there is still someone who is interested in this ancient feature. I still use it, but most of the time I find myself using up-arrow to recall past commands.

Twenty-five years ago I had `\!` as a component of my `PS1` to be able to number past commands and recall them like `!54`. I don’t remember when I decided that it wasn’t useful any more... Now I use `!!`, `!-2`, `!-3` and above all `!$` and `!$:h` often, but not much more.

Anyway, you seem to ask two different things:

- Correct previous command:

  ```
  $ mv -r from to
  $ !!:s/-r//
  mv  from to
  ```

`!:s/-r//` can be used instead of `!!:s/-r//`. The `s/<string>/<replacement>/` modifier replaces the first occurrence of `<string>` with `<replacement>`.

- Address command name

  ```
  $ mv from to
  $ echo !:0
  mv
  ```

Comment: Oh, yes. thanks this was it. I realized there are search parameters and even ways to find the head and tail of a path. I love using bangs since I am a bit of an aggressive shell user and loves typing redundantly sometimes.

Comment: You can also use `^` shortcut : `^-r^`.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could simplify the use of arguments 2 and 3 like in this example:

```
$ echo -r movableFolder/ targetFolder/
-r movableFolder/ targetFolder/

$ echo !:2*
movableFolder/ targetFolder/
```

All is documented in man bash:

> Word Designators
>   Word  designators  are  used  to select desired words from the event.  A : separates the event specification from the word designator.  It may be omitted if the word designator begins with a ^, $, *, -, or  %.   Words are  numbered from the beginning of the line, with the first word being denoted by 0 (zero).  Words are inserted into the current line separated by single spaces.
>
> ```
>   0 (zero)  The zeroth word.  For the shell, this is the command word.
>   n         The nth word.
>   ^         The first argument. That is, word 1.
>   $         The last word. This is usually the last argument, but will
>             expand to the zeroth word if there is only one word in the line.
>   %         The word matched by the most recent `?string?' search.
>   x-y       A range of words; `-y' abbreviates `0-y'.
>   *         All  of the words but the zeroth. This is a synonym for `1-$'.
>             It is not an error to use * if there is just one word in the event;
>             the empty string is returned in that case.
>   x*        Abbreviates x-$.
>   x-        Abbreviates x-$ like x*, but omits the last word.
> ```
>
> If a word designator is supplied without an event specification, the previous command is used as the event.

And therefore, after this line has been used:

```
$ echo -r movableFolder/ targetFolder/
echo -r movableFolder/ targetFolder/
```

this will work:

```
$ !:0 !:2*
movableFolder/ targetFolder/
```

Also this:

```
$ !:0 !:2-$
movableFolder/ targetFolder/
```